# How can I call the basic methods of an R graphic device?

Tags: r, graphics

The `devout` package lists several methods that are implemented by an R Graphics device. The full list is:

```
names(devinfo$device_call)
#>  [1] "activate"        "cap"             "circle"          "clip"           
#>  [5] "close"           "deactivate"      "eventHelper"     "holdflush"      
#>  [9] "line"            "locator"         "metricInfo"      "mode"           
#> [13] "newFrameConfirm" "newPage"         "onExit"          "path"           
#> [17] "polygon"         "polyline"        "raster"          "rect"           
#> [21] "size"            "strWidth"        "strWidthUTF8"    "text"           
#> [25] "textUTF8"
```

Is it possible to *directly* call these methods on a given graphics device, from within R?

Comment: Seems hard ... ?? I don't see anything in the R internals documentation ...

Comment: Yeah... I wonder if it is even possible by writing C.